# How to call a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, blocks

I have included in my theme a new javascript library(Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion) which converts horizontal tabs to accordion.
So I have included in my .info theme 
scripts[] = js/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js

Then,according to the instructions,I have to call the javascript function $('#demoTab').easyResponsiveTabs();

My question is:Where to add this javascript function?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can continue `easyResponsiveTabs.js` as normal JS and add your function call. Also you can call this function almost anywhere (like tpl.php file), even in the block/node (where you are using this script for conversion) wrapped in the `<script>` tag like:

```
<script>
$('#demoTab').easyResponsiveTabs();
</script>
```

I would go with [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in `template.php` file of your theme.

## Update

Using [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) you can do it like this:

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery("#demoTab").easyResponsiveTabs();', 'inline');
```

Comment: I have included this code inside the template.php file of my theme(cloudy theme):
cloudy_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
   drupal_add_js($('#demoTab').easyResponsiveTabs();); 
}
However I take a WSOD-error.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If that is your code, then you need to add some quotes around the JavaScript string that you are passing to drupal_add_js().

Comment: I added them so the code is:
cloudy_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
   drupal_add_js('$('#demoTab').easyResponsiveTabs();'); 
}
still no luck :(

Comment: Thank you for the answer,now I don't take an error,actually I forgot to add the "function" to my code and also the hook_preprocess_page was already declared,so I fixed both of them.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easy way of adding JavaScript/jQuery is by using [JSinjector module](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector). Enable the module and goto `Admin -> Config -> Development -> JS injector`, add your jQuery. In JS injector body section, place your script using the function call as:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

          // your script goes here
$('#demoTab').easyResponsiveTabs();

}
};
})(jQuery);
```

Then, you can select inline/preprocessor type.